# Data does not refresh in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I'm updating some datasets in Power BI Desktop, even though they update the data in the Data window, the Report window doesn't. The information I need to display is some contained in measures and other in calculated columns, till now neither of them is updating the data.

As an example, I have this dataset initially:

```
Date             Type             Sales
01/01/2019       A                1
01/01/2019       B                3
```

But then I refresh the data and I get:

```
Date             Type             Sales
01/01/2019       A                1
01/01/2019       B                3
01/02/2019       A                4
01/02/2019       B                5
```

So, my visuals only show the information from January. I also have a calendar table and when I make a table with the `Date` and `Sales` it only displays the `Sales` of January.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your data tab is properly updated, but you are not seeing the complete data in the visuals, then it would be because you have applied some filters on the visuals. You can click on the small filter icon which pops up when you hover over the top right section of the visual, to see what filters are affecting the visual. If there are any unwanted filters remove them. There are no gaps between what you see in the data tab and what is available as base data for your visuals. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to check your relationship and the calendar table. Make sure you have all the relevant dates in the calendar table as well.

Comment: I realized the relationship between calendar table and the data was not direct, now the refreshing data is shown :) thank u!!